# Strange maths while filtering array by elements in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was trying to remove ids from a new request that have already been requested. In the code below I was expecting for the ...56 id to be removed and only the ...81 id to remain. 56 was removed but to my surprise 81 had been decreased to 80.

```
const oldIds = [
  10032789416531456
];

const newIds = [
  10032789435529381,
  10032789416531456
];

const result = newIds.filter(newId => !oldIds.some(oldId => oldId === newId));
console.log(result)
//Expected result is: [10032789435529381], instead I get [10032789435529380]
```

I was able to solve this problem by using strings for ids instead of numbers.

Comment: You're exceeding the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` value with those values. They cannot be represented exactly in JavaScript numbers. Using strings is probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type `10032789435529381` in the js console, it returns `10032789435529380`. You've exceeded the capacity of the javascript integer, causing it to be treated as a less precise floating point number.

This is part of the reason why using strings for IDs instead of numbers is typically recommended.